# Should I handle/catch these exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

The following exceptions are probably very similar:

- `ArgumentException`
- `ArgumentNullException`
- `InvalidOperationException`
- `ObjectDisposedException`.

  1. Should I throw them in my code?
  2. Should I catch them?
  3. `InvalidOperationException` is a very vague and broad exception as it means a method tries something that is not possible due to state (e.g. start a win svc which may not be startable).

Comment: is it possible that your code will throw these exceptions? If so then catch them. Some code would be useful

Comment: Do not catch any exceptions unless you are expecting them and you know *specifically* how to handle them. If not, don't catch them. Let them bubble up the stack. This is what they're designed to do. And there's no case where you should catch `ObjectDisposedException`. That indicates a bug in your program; you want to fix that, not catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you're doing. Except for the ObjectDisposedException, which is something you should leave to the run-time, all of these are acceptable to throw in appropriate situations.

Do you expect some of these to occur then by all means, catch them and handle the situation appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should throw the most specific exception you can. This gives the consumer the best possible chance of handling/understanding exceptions.

So for example,

- Throw ArgumnetNullException, when the arg is null Throw
- ArgumentOutofRange exception when the arg is out of range The
- ArgumentException is the arg is invalid for some other reason.

InvalidOperationException is quite broad, and often used as the catchall when more specific options aren't suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the self-made method parameter validators (often named like Guard, Arguments, etc...) are throw these exceptions in case of invalid arguments:

- ArgumentException - when method parameter is wrong
- ArgumentNullException - when method parameter is null

I believe MSDN has pretty detailed description of when to throw such exceptions,

> **ArgumentException** is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one
>   of the passed arguments does not meet the parameter specification of
>   the called method. All instances of ArgumentException should carry a
>   meaningful error message describing the invalid argument, as well as
>   the expected range of values for the argument.
>
> **ArgumentNullException** is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the 
>   passed arguments is null but should never be null.
>
> **InvalidOperationException** is used in cases when the failure to invoke
>   a method is caused by reasons other than invalid arguments. For
>   example, InvalidOperationException is thrown by:
>
> - MoveNext if objects of a collection are modified after the
>     enumerator is created.
> - GetString if the resource set is closed before the method call is
>     made.